# Fatal Error in WordPress functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I was adding some code to alter the 'cart' option on WordPress and had to add some code into my `functions.php`.

I followed the instructions, added the code to my `functions.php` file, and received the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare `enqueue_font_awesome()` (previously declared in `/home2/xxx/public_html/xxx/wp-content/themes/connection/functions.php:11`) in `/home2/xxx/public_html/fba-product-designer.com/wp-content/themes/connection/functions.php` on line 21

I cannot access the administrative URI, and my website now shows the above message. I can go back and edit the `functions.php` so I'm hoping there is an easy fix in my code.

Comment: provide relevant code here itself

Comment: StackOverflow does not work like that. Step 1: Delete the code you added a nd update the script, that will help you. Step 2: Post the code **here** otherwise no one will be willing to help you

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you messed up. But you have the exact path of the file where the error occurs. You should use an FTP client and your favorite plain text editor to alter this file in order to fix it. As said above, SO is not the place for those issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just messed up his WP installation and cannot log back into the WP GUI to fix it. This is a sad situation... But SO is not the place to get such help.

Answer (score 2):

I'll edit this if you post your source code in your question, but your error is suggesting that you redeclared `enqueue_font_awesome()` on line 21 of `functions.php`. It originally exists on line 11.

Remove one or the other, and test. If one doesn't work, try removing the other and replacing the previously removed one.

This should resolve the error.